# Python netCDF: I accidentally wrote a unwanted variable in a netcdf file. Now a simple ds. var doesn't work anymore. What should I do?

Tags: python, netcdf

I open the netCDF file by xarray.
`ds ＝ xr.open_dataset(filename)` 
But there's an extra variable 「u」exsited already which I think I accidentally wrote in the file.I can't remember how I did it.
When I run  `newname ＝ ds. var` in the file, it doesn't work. But when I run the same code in the window, newname does occur in the variable window. What should I do to make it work in the file so that I can process thousands of files at one time？

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That's all I got.